# How do I model this Shipping Routes scenario?

Tags: c#, design, object-oriented-design

Trying to begin coding this solution.

I have a scenario as follows below:

> A shipping operator has a network of routes to various ports, the routes are specified explicitly below
>
> - Buenos Aires --> New York - 6 days
> - New York --> Liverpool - 4 days
> - Liverpool --> Casablanca - 3 days
> - Casablanca --> Liverpool - 3 days
> - Cape Town --> New York - 8 days.

I later need to calculate the following:

> - What is the total journey time (Any route ie: Buenos Aires>New York>Liverpool)
> - Find the shortest journey time (Any route ie: New York>New York)
> - Find the no of routes from Liverpool to Liverpool with a max no of 3 stops
> - Find the no of routes from Buenos Aires to Liverpool with exactly 4 stops.
> - Find the no of routes from Liverpool to Liverpool where the journey time is less than or equal to 25 days.

I now need an eloquent model for this problem, something that will enable me to do the calculations later.

First, what's the best way to store all the valid routes, which will not change at all. Should they be stored in an array, arraylist or something else. An array would make it unwieldy.

My first thoughts are that I have a ship class representing a total journey that can be used by my methods later. And I have a route class which represents all of the routes and possesses the methods to calculate valid routes, no of stops etc.

I'm sure i'm overthinking this but any help on how to model this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with Graph Theory?

Comment: And the [Travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: Yes @MSalters i'm familiar with Graph theory, I looked at a graph with directed edges to represent the valid routes.
However thought it might be too ambitious for this scenario.

Comment: @SolilquyOfChaos: The graph is small enough that you don't absolutely need it. At that point you're almost answering the questions by hand. But the intent of this question really is to make the small graph and solve the 5 problems on that graph.

Comment: @MSalters Ok I've found the Graph class [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.graphmodel.graph.aspx], now will attempt to solve with the Graph

Comment: @SolilquyOfChaos: Please note, that's a Graph class intended for Dependency Graphs. Dependency Graphs have an important property : they're never cyclic. And your graph definitely is cyclic.